# How to open new Finder tab without showing parent directory structure on the left?

Tags: macos, finder, folders, catalina

After upgrading from macOS High Sierra to Mojave, I can’t open a new window or tab in a specific folder without showing all the directories from root downwards. I hoped that it would change after upgrading to Catalina but it didn’t happen.  I am using column view.

What can be done to make it show only the folder's contents from the beginning, not the previous folders?

**How I would like to see it:**
 It opens the folder "my tickets" straightaway. I don't have to see the previous folder structure. 
[image]

**What currently happens:** When I get to folder "my tickets" and right click it to open in new tab, it opens all the directory structure again. There's no point in opening it in new window.
[image]

**Overview**
[image]

Comment: Right or control click on desired folder and open in new tab doesn’t work for you?

Comment: @bjbk Apparently ,that's how OP seems to be opening the folder. And I, on mojave can confirm, that *open in new tab* or *open in new window* (press alt in right click menu ) show full structure.

Comment: When I click on a folder and select open in new tab I get the contents of the folder in the new tab.  I use list view by default.  I guess I just don’t understand what the OP is looking for. Sorry

Comment: Folders open for me as the OP's screen shot shows for me in column view too.  Both Mojave and Catalina.

Comment: Do you mean you want to see the contents of child folders too?  What if there is more than one?  Would not be possible in Column view.  Please update with more information please.  Would love to help if I can!  Cheers

Comment: My English is not so good, so I will try to explain my problem once more. I work with lots of documents and I need to get to a folder as fast as possible. It used to be Ok when on my MacBook Pro was macOS High Sierra. After upgrading Finder doesn't work properly.  "What currently happens": When I get to folder "my tickets" and right click it to open in new tab, it opens all the directory again. There's no point in opening it in new window. In picture "How I would like to see it" you can see the difference: it opens the folder "my tickets" straightaway.

Comment: I think it's pretty clear what the OP is asking...

Answer (score 1):

What you may require is to 'root' the folder that you need into the sidebar.

Is it as simple as dragging the folder that you want into the sidebar? If not I may have misunderstood your question.

There is probably a way to default this behaviour by using `default write com.apple.finder.plist <somevariable> -bool true` (or similar) but I would not be able to tell you the particular variable without spending a deal of time on it. Apple prefer you to use the GUI in a lot of cases, but editing the plist files generally grant you more granular control over the system.

Comment: could you explain what 'root' does ? I agree that the sidebar folders appear without previous structure, but doing so for every "open in new tab" action seems ridiculous

Comment: Sure, it's a bit of a misnomer tbh, I think. `Root` with Unix-like systems is traditionally the super user. In this case, however, apple appear to have used the word to describe a folder that is treated like a 'root' folder - i.e. at the base of the filesystem, but purely for display purposes. I was trying to find a plist setting which may provide permanent changes for the OP, but ran out of time last night. Agree that it seems ridiculous. There has to be a better way of doing it for multiple folders. This should get the OP going for now though.